# In Mac Excel 2011, how to conditionally format as percentage or currency based on text in another cell?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

As far as I can tell, the Conditional Formatting feature doesn't support percentages.  You can format styles (color, font, etc.), but not the actual content presentation itself.

I have two columns, one that labels the type of data that is in the second column, and then the data itself.  For instance:

```
A           B
bids        0.0012
spreader    on
potency     0.75
```

I would like to format the data in column B, based on the content of column A.  So for instance B1 should be currency, B2 should be text ("General" would be fine), and B3 should be Percentage.

Since I don't believe I can use regular conditional formatting, what are my options here?  And if I'm wrong in my premise, please point me at how to accomplish what I'm seeking.

Comment: C'mon man, this isn't the place for that kind of question. SO is for specific programming problems. Try over at SuperUser

Comment: Well that's funny because I specifically searched for the best form for such an Excel question, and the accepted answer was that StackOverflow was best fit.  Makes no difference to me where I post... but I *did* try to do the right thing.  If an admin thinks this doesn't belong here, feel free to close it (or move it if you do that sort of thing).

Comment: Fair point but if everyone else was jumping off a cliff... would you do it too ;)

Comment: Sure.  Of course I'd be wearing a parachute, or perhaps a wingsuit...

Comment: Instead of conditional formatting which can be a pain with percentages, why not do a 3rd column that checks the value to the left `=IF(B2<0.5,"true","false)` style?

Comment: Yeah I considered something like that, I was just really hoping to not have to add a whole other column just for this.  Just feels like bloat to me.  I might do it if I have no other option, but I feel fairly confident there's a more elegant solution hiding somewhere.  P.S. question asked now in SU.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I reference previous rows of data all the time so I rarely ever use filters on it.  Once in a while for certain things, but not often.  I need to format the cells in that column individually depending on the text in column A.  So far I can't find any way to do it, not even by adding extra columns as @ScottMcGready suggested.

Comment: I cannot think of anything better than to use macro. This [site](http://www.excelhowto.com/macros/formatting-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-vba/) may help.

Comment: Yeah someone else just suggested a macro approach as well... definitely far from ideal but if I get frustrated enough maybe I'll go that route.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So unfortunately the answer is that this is not possible with Mac Excel 2011, but is possible in Windows using the standard Conditional Formatting features.